# How do I retrieve photos from venues/search

Tags: foursquare

The docs say that there should be a photos array in each venue response but in my tests and in the API explorer, I am unable to get any results.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fnear%3DSan+Francisco

Sometimes the response will contain a photos array with the counts but never any photos. Interestingly the same query on venues/explore does return the photos if the venuePhotos variable is set to '1'.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/explore%3Fnear%3DSan+Francisco%26venuePhotos%3D1

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...its work for me..

Get individual venue details using this

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/your_venue_id?oauth_token=your_oauth_token&v=20130508

then check the photos object in the response, then add suffix and prefix parameter to get the final image url.